# Unix Shell script to remove duplicate files with the same filename but different file extension

Tags: shell, unix, pdf, doc

I am brand new to Unix shell scripting. Got basic knowledge of commands and trying to write my first script. 
The problem: I have an archive folder with large amount of PDF and DOC files. Lot of them have both PDF and DOC version e.g. hello.doc and hello.pdf. I would like to remove all the pdf versions of these "duplicates" with identical filename and it does not matter if the actual file content is the same or not.
I tried for past week to look for some solution but usually I found only solutions based on the file content.

Thank you very much for help.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please have a look at the guides on [how to ask questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking), specifically [how to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like:

```
for i in *.doc; do
  pdffile=$(echo "$i"|sed 's/\.doc/\.pdf/')
  if [[ -f "$pdffile" ]]; then
    rm "$pdffile"
  fi
done
```

Which does: for each doc file in current directory, is a file has the same name, but with pdf, then remove the pdf file.

Comment: Thank you very much for the prompt response. I apologize for my "noobidity". I understand that  "i"  is a variable but do I still need to declare it first or can I implement the code as it is?

Comment: @PeterS You can run the code as it is, `i` is declared in the `for` statement

Comment: Hi I tried and always get the same error::::  rm: cannot remove ‘pdffile’: No such file or directory

Comment: did you copy well? ==> rm "$pdffile" not rm "pdffile"

Comment: Thank you very much, you was right, I forgot to add the $, it is working now!